# Change all buttons background color of WPF window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to add the style dynamically to button,below is the code i am using but it is not working for me

**First Way**

```
 public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             Style style = new Style
            {
                TargetType = typeof(Button)
            };

            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
            Resources.Add(typeof(Button), style);


        }
```

**second way**
one more thing i have tried with below second way also but it gives me error **After a 'SetterBase' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified**

```
Style style = this.FindResource("ButtonStyle1") as Style;

            Setter setter = (Setter)style.Setters[0];
            setter.Property. = false;
            Color orange1 = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFF3800C");
            setter.Value = new SolidColorBrush(orange1);
```

Comment: What is the reason for doing this? Depending on what you are doing, perhaps there is a better approach than trying to change a style in code.

Comment: @AndrewStephens I want to make my application theme based.so i am just start doing with button right now,after that i will make all the controls style dynamic

Comment: There are better ways to dynamically change an application theme, by having separate resource dictionaries that you switch in and out at runtime (Google "wpf dynamic theme change"). It may be easier and more "future proof" than altering the style properties in code.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStephens, actually i am new i wpf. can you post some code for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Windows Resources add

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This will change background of all buttons in window

Comment: want to change color dynamically not by static way as i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/managing-themes-in-wpf.html) starts describes a solution, although it stops short of a detailed breakdown; you should find all you need by looking at the author's code [here](https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.Themes/tree/master/Simple.Wpf.Themes).

The main class is the `ThemeManager` which provides a method to apply a theme to the application. The author represents a theme using a `Theme` class - the important bit is the `Uri` property. Essentially the `ThemeManager` loads the appropriate resource file from the Uri, and adds it to the application's MergedDictionaries collection (removing any existing theme resource first).

So a condensed (and untested) version of the author's code might go something like this:-

```
private ResourceDictionary _currentTheme;

public void ApplyTheme(Uri uri)
{
    if (_currentTheme != null)
    {
        // Unload the current theme.
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(_currentTheme);
    }

    var resourceDictionary = 
        Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;
    if (resourceDictionary != null)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
        _currentTheme = resourceDictionary;
    }
}
```

An example of a Uri would be:

```
var uri = new Uri(
    "/Wpf.TestHarness;component/Themes/RedTheme.xaml", 
    UriKind.Relative);
```

where `Wpf.TestHarness` is the name of the compiled assembly (without the .DLL or .EXE extension) containing the XAML resource files, and `/Themes/RedTheme.xaml' is the path to one of the XAML theme files embedded in that project (`component` is a required part of this "pack URI" path notation). Remember to set the build action of the XAML files in the project to "Page".

Now, create a style called "ButtonStyle1" in each of the theme files, but with different background colours for example. In your application I think you need to reference such styles using `DynamicResource` (someone correct me if I'm wrong), e.g.:-

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" ... />
```

Better still, don't name your styles. Just use the `TargetType`, to apply it to every control of that type:-

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">...</Style>
```

Good luck!